# textGrob placement relative to changing plot size

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I'm producing a whole pile of graphs of changing sizes. I want each graph to display a symbol (say, asterisk) at a specific point on the graph margin (top y-axis value), regardless of plot size. Right now I do it manually by defining x/y for each `textGrob`, but there has got to be a better way.

Plot size is determined by number of categories in the dataset (toy data below). Ideally, the output plots would have identical panel sizes (I'm assuming that can be controlled through defining margin sizes in inches and adding that value to the `height` parameter?). Widths don't usually change, but it would be nice to automate both x and y placements based on the defined device width (and plot margins).

Thanks so much!

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(20, 0, 1), y = rnorm(20, 0, 1), category = rep(c("a", "b"), each = 10))

## plot 1
sub <- df[df$category == "a",]
height = 2*length(unique(sub$category))
p <- ggplot(sub) + 
    geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    facet_grid(category ~ .) 


jpeg(filename = "fig1.jpg",
     width = 6, height = height, units = "in", pointsize = 12, res = 900,
     quality = 100)
g <- arrangeGrob(p, sub = textGrob("*", x = 0.07, y = 10.15, hjust = 0, vjust=0,   #### puts the top discharge value; might need to be adjusted manually in following years
    gp = gpar(fontsize = 15)))
grid.draw(g)
dev.off()



 ## plot 2

height = 2*length(unique(df$category))
p <- ggplot(df) + 
    geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    facet_grid(category ~ .)

jpeg(filename = "fig2.jpg",
     width = 6, height = height, units = "in", pointsize = 12, res = 900,
     quality = 100)
g <- arrangeGrob(p, sub = textGrob("*", x = 0.07, y = 23.1, hjust = 0, vjust=0,   #### puts the top discharge value; might need to be adjusted manually in following years
    gp = gpar(fontsize = 15)))
grid.draw(g)
dev.off()
```